# How /or what QGIS plugin do I use to open these layers? (they seem to be served by Geoserver)

Tags: qgis, geoserver, wms, wmts

I'm new to this field. I'm trying to open in QGIS the layers that are provided in this page: http://geoportal.asig.gov.al/(X(1)S(j2y2e0qp4wnyij4q2lvko2wt))/en/InfoandServices.aspx?lang=EN.

(each layer has a links option)

I have some links but I dont have any info on what standard are those, or how do I open them. (They seem to be served by Geoserver). I tried with OpenGeo Explorer plugin but those Links dont work. I also tried to add them as WMS/WMTS Layer in QGIS but nothing. (the legend of the layer appears some times, but the vector layer itself doesnt show up)

I have seen two types of links in that page so far. 
http://geoportal.asig.gov.al/Services/host/host.ashx?url=http://localhost:8080/geoserver/asig/wms&Version=1.1.1&srs=EPSG:32634&layers=view_alb_n
and

http://geoportal.asig.gov.al:85/utm34n/wmts/1.0.0/WMTSCapabilities.xml

Anyone knows what tool should I use to access & analyse those layers?

Answer (score 1):

You just can´t... The service behind seems to be a geoserver, thats right. But its not delivering the wmts directly but to the server side dynamic web page. There it is processed and delivered to you as .net webservice for your local client (your browser). This way you can´t access the geoserver (like in the xml document it is shown as localhost) because its not in the internet. Its often done this way that you can´t access data outside of the given webpage.

Comment: The localhost in those urls is an internal reference for the ASIG server/service.